# Where can I change the Certificate Thumbprint from a Sitecore IdentityServer website?

Tags: identity-server, certificate

I had to recreate my certs and after doing so and importing them into my IIS, I'm struggling now to find where exactly on the `Sitecore IdentityServer` website I must update its Thumbprint.

Has anyone changed this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is an XML instead of a config file on which we can do it.

`website.identityserver\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`

```
<Settings>
      <Sitecore>
        <IdentityServer>      
          <CertificateThumbprint>‎ABCB50CAB808CDD021A9850CF6BB8AA2B6A1B3AD</CertificateThumbprint>
```

Comment: Remember to recycle after changing this value. That had me stumped for a bit :)

Comment: And also update /App_Config/Connectionstrings.config with the new thumbprints and be sure that IIS_IUSRS can access the private key, done in Certificates MMC:
Right click certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys -> Add group "IIS_IUSRS"